# How to change Draggable component's original position

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working with the [react-native-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable?activeTab=readme) component.

```
return (
    <View >
        <Draggable x={75} y={100} renderSize={56} renderColor='black' renderText='A' isCircle shouldReverse onShortPressRelease={()=>alert('touched!!')}/> 
        <Draggable x={200} y={300} renderColor='red' renderText='B'/>
    </View>
);
```

By setting the shouldReverse prop to true, the draggable item smoothly returns to its original position.

However, I can't seem to dynamically update the "original position" of the draggable item by updating the position.x and position.y values, as in the following code:

```
    <View style={styles.answerContainer}>
        {answerParts.map((item, index) => (
            <Draggable
                key={item.index}
                x={item.position.x}
                y={item.position.y}
                disabled={item.placed}
                shouldReverse={!item.placed}
                onDragRelease={(event) => onReleaseItem(item, event)}
            >
                <View style={styles.draggableItem}>
                    <Text style={styles.draggableText}>{item.text}</Text>
                </View>
            </Draggable>
        ))}
    </View>
```

Any thoughts on how I can properly change the original location of a draggable React Native component?

Thanks!